# Square norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Exercise 21.2.7 (Stillwell).

> Suppose that $t^2 = u^2 + 2s^2$, for ordinary integers $s$, $t$, $u$.
> By considering the prime factorization of both sides in
> $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, show that $t$ is also of the form $p^2 + 2q^2$,
> for ordinary integers $p$, $q$.

If understand this statement correctly, it's false as is because

- $5^2 = 5^2 + 2\times 0^2$,
- but $5$ doesn't have the form $p^2 + 2q^2$ by inspection of small values for $p$ and $q$.

I suppose we should require that $s$ and $u$ are coprime for the conclusion to be true. Is this what was intended by Stillwell, or something else?

A proof goes like this. Define $z = u + s\sqrt{-2}$. Then $t^2 = z \overline{z}$. If $z$ is non-invertible, $p\mid z$ for some $p$ prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. Then $p\mid t$. Then $(t/p)^2 p = (z/p) \overline{p} (\overline{z} / \overline{p})$.

- If $p\mid (z/p) (\overline{z} / \overline{p})$, we are set.
- If $p\mid \overline{p}$, $p$ is associated to $\overline{p}$.

  - If $p = \overline{p}$, $p$ is integer. Then $p\in \{1, -1\}$ because $s$ and $u$ are coprime. This is where we use the additional condition. This branch contradicts that $p$ is prime.
  - If $-p = \overline{p}$, then $p\in \{\sqrt{-2}, -\sqrt{-2}\}$ because $s$ and $u$ are coprime. Then $p \overline{p} = 2$. Going one step backward, $2\mid t$ because $t^2 = z \overline{z}$ and $p \overline{p}\mid z \overline{z}$.

Some details were omitted.

Stillwell, John. *Mathematics and Its History.* 3rd ed., Springer Science & Business Media, 2010.

Comment: it would be typical to require $\gcd(s,t,u) = 1.$  Perhaps on an earlier page. Anyway, given any solution to $t^2 = u^2 + 2 s^2$   we create infinitely many annoying solutions $(\lambda t,  \lambda u, \lambda s).$   Let's see,    the primitive solutions of $x^2 + 2 y^2 = z^2$ are $x=|2m^2 - n^2|, \; y = 2mn, \; \; z = 2m^2 + n^2$